# How to detect whether there is a specific member variable in class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, g++, sfinae

For creating algorithm template function I need to know whether x or X (and y or Y) in class that is template argument. It may by useful when using my function for MFC CPoint class or GDI+ PointF class or some others. All of them use different x in them. My solution could be reduces to the following code:

```
template<int> struct TT {typedef int type;};
template<class P> bool Check_x(P p, typename TT<sizeof(&P::x)>::type b = 0) { return true; }
template<class P> bool Check_x(P p, typename TT<sizeof(&P::X)>::type b = 0) { return false; }

struct P1 {int x; };
struct P2 {float X; };
// it also could be struct P3 {unknown_type X; };

int main()
{
    P1 p1 = {1};
    P2 p2 = {1};

    Check_x(p1); // must return true
    Check_x(p2); // must return false

    return 0;
}
```

But it does not compile in Visual Studio, while compiling in the GNU C++. With Visual Studio I could use the following template:

```
template<class P> bool Check_x(P p, typename TT<&P::x==&P::x>::type b = 0) { return true; }
template<class P> bool Check_x(P p, typename TT<&P::X==&P::X>::type b = 0) { return false; }
```

But it does not compile in GNU C++. Is there universal solution?

UPD: Structures P1 and P2 here are only for example. There are could be any classes with unknown members.

P.S. Please, do not post C++11 solutions here because they are obvious and not relevant to the question.

Comment: I don't believe the second way is standard (integral constant expressions may not use op== with operands involving op&). But the first way looks right. What does msvc++ say about it?

Comment: @litb: Take a look at the link at the end of my answer - I think that explains the problem (both why compilers reject it, and whether it's really allowed by the C++98 Standard).

Comment: +1: Interesting challenge :-)

Comment: I've written a thorough explanation of the correct code to solve this problem, and it is available here: http://cpptalk.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/substitution-failure-is-not-an-error-2/ .
Sorry for making this comment twice, but i feel it belongs under the main post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Comment: The following post explains how you can detect if there is a member variable, even if it is PRIVATE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139547/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-private-member-variable-in-class?noredirect=1#comment113421398_64139547

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Another way is this one, which relies on [SFINAE for expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html) too. If the name lookup results in ambiguity, the compiler will reject the template

```
template<typename T> struct HasX { 
    struct Fallback { int x; }; // introduce member name "x"
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template<typename C, C> struct ChT; 

    template<typename C> static char (&f(ChT<int Fallback::*, &C::x>*))[1]; 
    template<typename C> static char (&f(...))[2]; 

    static bool const value = sizeof(f<Derived>(0)) == 2;
}; 

struct A { int x; };
struct B { int X; };

int main() { 
    std::cout << HasX<A>::value << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << HasX<B>::value << std::endl; // 0
}
```

It's based on a brilliant idea of someone on usenet.

Note: HasX checks for any data or function member called x, with arbitrary type. The sole purpose of introducing the member name is to have a possible ambiguity for member-name lookup - the type of the member isn't important.

Comment: At first I did not understand the idea. That is exactly what I needed. This solution works both in MSVC++ 2008 and g++4.2.4.

Comment: @litb: Do you have a link to the Usenet discussion?

Comment: yeah, hold your breath: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/tree/browse_frm/thread/4f7c7a96f9afbe44/c95a7b4c645e449f?pli=1 (linked from the SO thread you link too by one guy). No worries if you don't get immediately what that guy's code does. It's very clever and took me quite a while too

Comment: I can't quite see how is_call_possible discussed there relates to the code in this answer.

Comment: its "has_member" is doing the stuff that my code does too :) it's using that first, because only then "using type::operator();" won't raise a compile error ("operator()" then is guaranteed to exist)

Comment: Got it now, don't know why I missed it on my quick scan through. Codepad.org looks cool :-)

Comment: I added a post on my blog about this, hope you guys don't mind :)
at http://cpptalk.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/substitution-failure-is-not-an-error-1/
Interesting read.

Comment: @rmn, it does *not* check for an `integer` member though, it checks for any data or function member called `x`, with arbitrary type. The sole purpose of introducing the member name is to have a possible ambiguity for member-name lookup - the *type* of the member isn't important.

Comment: @litb btw, if we only wanted to know if there's an integer member by the name of x, we could've entirely dropped the whole Fallback part and just have the substitution fail due to not finding that member. Right?

Comment: @rmn, yeah. It would simplify to just `ChT<int C::*, &C::x>*` for checking for an `int` member. Perhaps i should have chosen another type for the tests to make it more clear that only the name is important, though.

Comment: It would look like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/possible-for-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/264088#264088 . Note, however, that it has drawbacks: It will fail if the type has inherited the member (because it would need an implicit conversion from `T Base::*` to `T Derived::*`. I haven't yet found a solution for that problem - all "solutions" have their drawbacks, it seems.

Comment: now a full explanation of this code is pubished.. at: http://cpptalk.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/substitution-failure-is-not-an-error-2/ 
litb, you are more than welcome to verify i got it correctly :)

Comment: Sure that's is how the matters are, i think :)

Comment: Awesome stuff. It works on member functions too, even inherited. ( i needed to check for functions myself )

Comment: How is possible to call the instantiated method from the template class (f) to return a reference to the member found in typename T?

Answer (score 135):

Here is a solution simpler than 
[Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb)'s [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1007175/1137388). It requires C++11.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = int>
struct HasX : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct HasX <T, decltype((void) T::x, 0)> : std::true_type { };
```

**Update**: A quick example and the explanation on how this works.

For these types:

```
struct A { int x; };
struct B { int y; };
```

we have `HasX<A>::value == true` and `HasX<B>::value == false`. Let's see why.

First recall that `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` have a `static constexpr bool` member named `value` which is set to `false` and `true`, respectively. Hence, the two templates `HasX` above inherit this member. (The first template from `std::false_type` and the second one from `std::true_type`.)

Let's start simple and then proceed step by step until we get to the code above.

1) Starting point:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct HasX : std::false_type { };
```

In this case, there's no surprise: `HasX` derives from `std::false_type` and hence `HasX<bool, double>::value == false` and `HasX<bool, int>::value == false`.

2) Defaulting `U`:

```
// Primary template
template <typename T, typename U = int>
struct HasX : std::false_type { };
```

Given that `U` defaults to `int`, `Has<bool>` actually means `HasX<bool, int>` and thus, `HasX<bool>::value == HasX<bool, int>::value == false`.

3) Adding a specialization:

```
// Primary template
template <typename T, typename U = int>
struct HasX : std::false_type { };

// Specialization for U = int
template <typename T>
struct HasX<T, int> : std::true_type { };
```

In general, thanks to the primary template, `HasX<T, U>` derives from `std::false_type`. However, there exists a specialization for `U = int` which derives from `std::true_type`. Therefore, `HasX<bool, double>::value == false` but `HasX<bool, int>::value == true`.

Thanks to the default for `U`, `HasX<bool>::value == HasX<bool, int>::value == true`.

4) `decltype` and a fancy way to say `int`:

A little digression here but, please, bear with me.

Basically (this is not entirely correct), `decltype(expression)` yields the type of  *expression*. For instance, `0` has type `int` thus, `decltype(0)` means `int`. Analogously, `1.2` has type `double` and thus, `decltype(1.2)` means `double`.

Consider a function with this declaration:

```
char func(foo, int);
```

where `foo` is some class type. If `f` is an object of type `foo`, then `decltype(func(f, 0))` means `char` (the type returned by `func(f, 0)`).

Now, the expression `(1.2, 0)` uses the (built-in) comma operator which evaluates the two sub-expressions in order (that is, first `1.2` and then `0`), discards the first value and results in the second one. Hence,

```
int x = (1.2, 0);
```

is equivalent to

```
int x = 0;
```

Putting this together with `decltype` gives that `decltype(1.2, 0)` means `int`. There's nothing really special about `1.2` or `double` here. For instance, `true` has type `bool` and `decltype(true, 0)` means `int` as well.

What about a class type? For instace, what does `decltype(f, 0)` mean? It's natural to expect that this still means `int` but it might not be the case. Indeed, there might be an overload for the comma operator similar to the function `func` above that takes a `foo` and an `int` and returns a `char`. In this case, `decltype(foo, 0)` is `char`.

How can we avoid the use of a overload for the comma operator? Well, there's no way to overload the comma operator for a `void` operand and we can cast anything to `void`. Therefore, `decltype((void) f, 0)` means `int`. Indeed, `(void) f` casts `f` from `foo` to `void` which basically does nothing but saying that the expression must be considered as having type `void`. Then the built-in operator comma is used and `((void) f, 0)` results in `0` which has type `int`. Hence, `decltype((void) f, 0)` means `int`.

Is this cast really necessary? Well, if there's no overload for the comma operator taking `foo` and `int` then this isn't necessary. We can always inspect the source code to see if there's such operator or not. However, if this appear in a template and `f` has type `V` which is a template parameter, then it's no longer clear (or even impossible to know) whether such overload for the comma operator exists or not. To be generic we cast anyway.

Bottom line: `decltype((void) f, 0)` is a fancy way to say `int`.

5) SFINAE:

This is a whole science ;-) OK I'm exagerating but it's not very simple either. So I'll keep the explanation to the bare minimum.

SFINAE stands for Substitution Failure is Not An Error. It means that when a template parameter is substituted by a type, an illegal C++ code might appear but, *in some circunstances*, instead of aborting compilation the compiler simply ignores the offending code as if it wasn't there. Let's see how it applies to our case:

```
// Primary template
template <typename T, typename U = int>
struct HasX : std::false_type { };

// Specialization for U = int
template <typename T>
struct HasX <T, decltype((void) T::x, 0)> : std::true_type { };
```

Here, again, `decltype((void) T::x, 0)` is a fancy way to say `int` but with the benefit of SFINAE.

When `T` is substituted with a type, an invalid construct might appear. For instance, `bool::x` is not valid C++, so substituting `T` with `bool` in `T::x` yields an invalid construct. Under the SFINAE principle, the compiler doesn't reject the code, it simply ignores (parts of) it. More precisely, as we have seen`HasX<bool>` means actually `HasX<bool, int>`. The specialization for `U = int` should be selected but, while instantiating it, the compiler finds `bool::x` and ignores the template specialization altogether as if it didn't exist.

At this point, the code is essencially the same as in case (2) above where just the primary template exists. Hence, `HasX<bool, int>::value == false`.

The same argument used for `bool` holds for `B` since `B::x` is an invalid construct (`B` has no member `x`). However, `A::x` is OK and the compiler sees no issue in instantiating the specialization for `U = int` (or, more precisely, for `U = decltype((void) A::x, 0)`). Hence, `HasX<A>::value == true`.

6) Unnaming `U`:

Well, looking at the code in (5) again, we see that the name `U` is not used anywhere but in its declaration (`typename U`). We can then unname the second template argument and we obtain the code shown at the top of this post.

Comment: @Jurak Blaho: The issue is GCC 4.7.2. It works with Clang 3.2 and IIRC it also works with GCC 4.8. (It's a shame that [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/) hasn't been working for a while.)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how this works, please?

Comment: @DarioP: I've added an update with the explanation. As you can see the explanation is quite lenghty because the correct amount of details always depends on reader's knowledge. For the benefit of beginners I assumed very little. I hope this is clear but not boring.

Comment: Thanks, I would up-vote for the second time if I could! This is brilliant!

Comment: This is the cleanest and simplest implementation I've seen. The problems with GCC were fixed, for me, by making the defaulted template argument `void` instead of `int`, and then removing the comma operator stuff in the `decltype` - http://ideone.com/QZHfai

Comment: Best explanation! Thats how it should be done! There was so much more to it than I first thought! :-)

Comment: Got this to work with Macros.
'#define DEFINE_MEMBER_CHECKER(member) \
    template<typename T, typename V = int> \
    struct has_ ## member : std::false_type { }; \
    template<typename T> \
    struct has_ ## member<T, \
        decltype((void)T:: ## member  \
            , 0) \
        > : std::true_type {};

#define HAS_MEMBER(C, member) \
    has_ ## member<C>::value'
thanks to Andy Prowl example.

Comment: The following post explains how you can detect if there is a member variable, even if it is PRIVATE. It is based on the above solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139547/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-private-member-variable-in-class?noredirect=1#comment113421398_64139547

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that the `int` in the generic template argument, and `0` in the specialization does not matter, i.e. replacing it with `bool` and `false`, respectively,  essentially does the exact same thing?

Comment: @tartaruga_casco_mole Yes, your understanding is correct. I've chosen `int` and `0` just to save typing :-) Also as @wakjah has pointed out in their comment, this can be further simplified by using `void` instead of `int` or `bool`.

Comment: Wouldn't have understood the answer without reading the breakdown, by far the best explanation Ive seen of this concept

Comment: In the primary template, if the default template type is `not void`(for example, int), for the specialization, it seems `decltype(T::x, 1)` is still working (no need to use `decltype((void)T::x, 1)`. But, if the default template type of the primary template is `void`,  `decltype((void)T::x)` is necessary(instead,  even `decltype(T::x)` doesn't generate compilation error but gets wrong answer). Anyone can figure it out?
Also, what's the difference between `(void)T::x` and `void(T::x)`? I tried both of them, and both worked.

Answer (score 36):

I got redirected here from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522939/check-whether-a-field-exists-in-a-struct) which has been closed as a duplicate of this one. I know it's an old thread, but I just wanted to suggest an alternative (simpler?) implementation that works with C++11. Supposing we want to check whether a certain class has a member variable called `id`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_id : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_id<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().id, void())> : std::true_type { };
```

That's it. And here is how it would be used ([*live example*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f1b5a38d87de415)):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X { int id; };
struct Y { int foo; };

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << has_id<X>::value << endl;
    cout << has_id<Y>::value << endl;
}
```

Things can be made even simpler with a couple of macros:

```
#define DEFINE_MEMBER_CHECKER(member) \
    template<typename T, typename V = bool> \
    struct has_ ## member : false_type { }; \
    template<typename T> \
    struct has_ ## member<T, \
        typename enable_if< \
            !is_same<decltype(declval<T>().member), void>::value, \
            bool \
            >::type \
        > : true_type { };

#define HAS_MEMBER(C, member) \
    has_ ## member<C>::value
```

Which could be used this way:

```
using namespace std;

struct X { int id; };
struct Y { int foo; };

DEFINE_MEMBER_CHECKER(foo)

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << HAS_MEMBER(X, foo) << endl;
    cout << HAS_MEMBER(Y, foo) << endl;
}
```

Comment: A nice solution, you'll run into problems though if X has a private member variable id.

Comment: I don't think you need `declval` at all, in my testing `decltype(T::id, void())` works fine

Answer (score 13):

We can use a [C++20 requires expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_expressions) to solve this problem. h/t to [@lefticus](https://twitter.com/lefticus) who recently posted this method in [C++ Weekly - Ep 242 - Design By Introspection in C++20 (concepts + if constexpr](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sy32kAtsIKg&feature=youtu.be):

```
#include <iostream>

struct P1 {int x;};
struct P2 {float X;};

bool has_x(const auto &obj) {
    if constexpr (requires {obj.x;}) {
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
}

int main()
{
    P1 p1 = {1};
    P2 p2 = {1};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_x(p1) << "\n"; 
    std::cout << has_x(p2) << "\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```

You can see it [live here](https://godbolt.org/z/EefYM5).

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: I've recently done some more with the code I posted in my original answer, so I'm updating this to account for changes/additions.**

Here are some usage snippets:
*The guts for all this are farther down

**Check for member `x` in a given class.  Could be var, func, class, union, or enum:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(x);
bool has_x = has_member_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member function `void x()`:**

```
//Func signature MUST have T as template variable here... simpler this way :\
CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_SIG_CHECK(x, void (T::*)(), void__x);
bool has_func_sig_void__x = has_member_func_void__x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member variable `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(x);
bool has_var_x = has_member_var_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member class `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(x);
bool has_class_x = has_member_class_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member union `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(x);
bool has_union_x = has_member_union_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for member enum `x`:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(x);
bool has_enum_x = has_member_enum_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Check for any member function `x` regardless of signature:**

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(x);
CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK(x);
bool has_any_func_x = has_member_func_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

OR

```
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECKS(x);  //Just stamps out the same macro calls as above.
bool has_any_func_x = has_member_func_x<class_to_check_for_x>::value;
```

**Details and core:**

```
/*
    - Multiple inheritance forces ambiguity of member names.
    - SFINAE is used to make aliases to member names.
    - Expression SFINAE is used in just one generic has_member that can accept
      any alias we pass it.
*/

template <typename... Args> struct ambiguate : public Args... {};

template<typename A, typename = void>
struct got_type : std::false_type {};

template<typename A>
struct got_type<A> : std::true_type {
    typedef A type;
};

template<typename T, T>
struct sig_check : std::true_type {};

template<typename Alias, typename AmbiguitySeed>
struct has_member {
    template<typename C> static char ((&f(decltype(&C::value))))[1];
    template<typename C> static char ((&f(...)))[2];

    //Make sure the member name is consistently spelled the same.
    static_assert(
        (sizeof(f<AmbiguitySeed>(0)) == 1)
        , "Member name specified in AmbiguitySeed is different from member name specified in Alias, or wrong Alias/AmbiguitySeed has been specified."
    );

    static bool const value = sizeof(f<Alias>(0)) == 2;
};
```

***Macros (El Diablo!):***

**CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK:**

```
//Check for any member with given name, whether var, func, class, union, enum.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(member)                                         \
                                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>                             \
struct Alias_##member;                                                      \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct Alias_##member <                                                     \
    T, std::integral_constant<bool, got_type<decltype(&T::member)>::value>  \
> { static const decltype(&T::member) value; };                             \
                                                                            \
struct AmbiguitySeed_##member { char member; };                             \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct has_member_##member {                                                \
    static const bool value                                                 \
        = has_member<                                                       \
            Alias_##member<ambiguate<T, AmbiguitySeed_##member>>            \
            , Alias_##member<AmbiguitySeed_##member>                        \
        >::value                                                            \
    ;                                                                       \
}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member variable with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(var_name)                                   \
                                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>                             \
struct has_member_var_##var_name : std::false_type {};                      \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct has_member_var_##var_name<                                           \
    T                                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                                               \
        bool                                                                \
        , !std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::var_name)>::value   \
    >                                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_SIG_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member function with given name AND signature.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_SIG_CHECK(func_name, func_sig, templ_postfix)    \
                                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>                             \
struct has_member_func_##templ_postfix : std::false_type {};                \
                                                                            \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct has_member_func_##templ_postfix<                                     \
    T, std::integral_constant<                                              \
        bool                                                                \
        , sig_check<func_sig, &T::func_name>::value                         \
    >                                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member class with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(class_name)               \
                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>             \
struct has_member_class_##class_name : std::false_type {};  \
                                                            \
template<typename T>                                        \
struct has_member_class_##class_name<                       \
    T                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                               \
        bool                                                \
        , std::is_class<                                    \
            typename got_type<typename T::class_name>::type \
        >::value                                            \
    >                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member union with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(union_name)               \
                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>             \
struct has_member_union_##union_name : std::false_type {};  \
                                                            \
template<typename T>                                        \
struct has_member_union_##union_name<                       \
    T                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                               \
        bool                                                \
        , std::is_union<                                    \
            typename got_type<typename T::union_name>::type \
        >::value                                            \
    >                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK:**

```
//Check for member enum with given name.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(enum_name)                 \
                                                            \
template<typename T, typename = std::true_type>             \
struct has_member_enum_##enum_name : std::false_type {};    \
                                                            \
template<typename T>                                        \
struct has_member_enum_##enum_name<                         \
    T                                                       \
    , std::integral_constant<                               \
        bool                                                \
        , std::is_enum<                                     \
            typename got_type<typename T::enum_name>::type  \
        >::value                                            \
    >                                                       \
> : std::true_type {}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK:**

```
//Check for function with given name, any signature.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK(func)          \
template<typename T>                            \
struct has_member_func_##func {                 \
    static const bool value                     \
        = has_member_##func<T>::value           \
        && !has_member_var_##func<T>::value     \
        && !has_member_class_##func<T>::value   \
        && !has_member_union_##func<T>::value   \
        && !has_member_enum_##func<T>::value    \
    ;                                           \
}
```

**CREATE_MEMBER_CHECKS:**

```
//Create all the checks for one member.  Does NOT include func sig checks.
#define CREATE_MEMBER_CHECKS(member)    \
CREATE_MEMBER_CHECK(member);            \
CREATE_MEMBER_VAR_CHECK(member);        \
CREATE_MEMBER_CLASS_CHECK(member);      \
CREATE_MEMBER_UNION_CHECK(member);      \
CREATE_MEMBER_ENUM_CHECK(member);       \
CREATE_MEMBER_FUNC_CHECK(member)
```

Comment: Variadic templates are not valid in the current C++ Standard.

Comment: Maybe important to point out that this is not working for inherited methods... but maybe that's intended. I guess std::integral_constant is the limitation here.

Answer (score 4):

[Boost.ConceptTraits](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction#Boost.ConceptTraits) provides between others some macros to define type traits, as for example `BOOST_TT_EXT_DEFINE_HAS_MEMBER(name)`, which defines a type trait of the form:

```
has_member_##name<T>
```

This gives true if T has a member type named . Note, however, that this won't detect reference type members.

In you case it will be enough to add in a header file

```
BOOST_TT_EXT_DEFINE_HAS_MEMBER_TYPE(x)
```

and check as follows

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(has_member_x<P1>::value);
```

The technique used is the same as the one explained on some of the preceding answers.

Unfortunately this library is no more maintained. Now that C++0x will not includes concept, this library together with SFINAE is a perfect replacement to work with most of the concepts.

Comment: Concept Traits is no more maintained because while that function evolved into these two ones:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/introspection.html
other functions went into Concepts_checks, for instance:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/concept_check/reference.htm#iterator-archetype

Comment: You are right. has_xxx is already in Boost and respond to the question. I don't agree for the second link as archetypes and concepts check are the two sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use specialization like this:

```
struct P1 {int x; };
struct P2 {int X; };

template<class P> 
bool Check_x(P p) { return true; }

template<> 
bool Check_x<P2>(P2 p) { return false; }
```

Comment: Because I don't know actually that struct P2 contains big X and P1 contains small x. These structs here just for example. There are could be any stucts or classes.

Comment: Then I don't see any way to recongnize it using templates (may be I am wrong). If the datatypes of x was different in P1 & P2 then may be we could have used sizeof to return true or false.

Comment: In my question there is the way (actually there are two different ways). But I don't know how to recognize it in both compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Are the functions (x, X, y, Y) from an abstract base class, or could they be refactored to be so? If so you can use the SUPERSUBCLASS() macro from Modern C++ Design, along with ideas from the answer to this question:

[Compile-time type based dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145814/compile-time-type-based-dispatch)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create template specializations of Check_x ?

```
template<> bool Check_x(P1 p) { return true; }
template<> bool Check_x(P2 p) { return false; }
```

Heck, when I think of it. If you only have two types, why do you even need templates for this?

Comment: There are more than only two types. Look at my comment to Naveen answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can get at compile time: `0 - not_member, 1 - is_object, 2 - is_function` for each required class and member - object or function: http://ideone.com/Fjm9u5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define IS_MEMBER(T1, M)    \
struct {        \
    struct verystrangename1 { bool M; };    \
    template<typename T> struct verystrangename2 : verystrangename1, public T { }; \
    \
    enum return_t { not_member, is_object, is_function }; \
    template<typename T, typename = decltype(verystrangename2<T>::M)> constexpr return_t what_member() { return not_member;  }  \
    template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_object_pointer<decltype(&T::M)>::value, return_t>::type constexpr what_member() { return is_object; }   \
    template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::M)>::value, return_t>::type constexpr what_member() { return is_function; }   \
    constexpr operator return_t() { return what_member<T1>(); } \
}

struct t {
    int aaa;
    float bbb;
    void func() {}
};

// Can't be in function
IS_MEMBER(t, aaa) is_aaa_member_of_t;
IS_MEMBER(t, ccc) is_ccc_member_of_t;
IS_MEMBER(t, func) is_func_member_of_t;

// known at compile time
enum { const_is_aaa_member_of_t = (int)is_aaa_member_of_t };
static constexpr int const_is_func_member_of_t = is_func_member_of_t;

int main() {        
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "0 - not_member, 1 - is_object, 2 - is_function \n\n" <<
        "is aaa member of t = " << is_aaa_member_of_t << std::endl << 
        "is ccc member of t = " << is_ccc_member_of_t << std::endl << 
        "is func member of t = " << is_func_member_of_t << std::endl << 
        std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0 - not_member, 1 - is_object, 2 - is_function 

is aaa member of t = 1
is ccc member of t = 0
is func member of t = 2
```

For class/struct:

```
struct t {
    int aaa;
    float bbb;
    void func() {}
};
```