# C++ type traits to check if class has operator/member

Tags: c++, class, templates, type-traits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Is it possible to use boost type traits or some other mechanism to check if a particular template parameter has an operator/function, e.g. `std::vector` as a template parameter has `operator[]`, while `std::pair` does not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't solve this via type traits because you'd have to define if for every possible name.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288) are the common solutions listed, which have one problem though: many STL implementations put common code in base classes and this method doesn't check for inherited names.

If you need to check for inherited members too, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions). The answer provides a solution that checks whether the class in question has a member of that name and can also check for const-ness and argument count. It fails however to check for the full signature including argument and return types and member visibility doesn't make a difference. You should be able to solve that partially by using the linked [`is_call_possible<>`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/e5fbc9305539f699) (haven't had time yet too look at it).

Comment: Every time I see that `is_call_possible` thread, a little bit of me gets scared.

Comment: my Russian is paying off, thanks

Comment: @GMan: I'll have to take heart and attack that next month ;)

Comment: Fresh code at https://github.com/jaredhoberock/is_call_possible.