# How to only set a member if it exists?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Edit: Sorry, this question is a duplicate. Original: [SFINAE to check for inherited member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions)

I have a templated function (in a class used for testing):

```
template <class CHandler>
void InitHandler(CHandler &handler)
{
    handler.setId(0);
    handler.SetCache(m_pCache.get());
    handler.m_pScience = m_pScience;
}
```

However it is possible that this function will may be called with a template argument that doesn't have an m_pScience member.

Can I use template metaprogramming to only set this member if it exists ?

Comment: If you are going to be the only person who maintains it for the rest of its life :)

Comment: I am almost certain this will only cause more headaches than it solves. I can't think of a way to do this that doesn't involve changes to your interface that imply you should re-think the design you've outlined here.

Comment: If the target class, in this case `CHandler`, does not have a public `m_pScience` member, the compiler will let you know when the template is instantiated.

Comment: This is almost, but not quite exactly the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005476/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-member-variable-in-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reimagining this answer: [How to detect whether there is a specific member variable in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005476/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-member-variable-in-class/1007175#1007175):

```
template<typename T> struct Hasm_pScience 
{ 
    struct Fallback { int m_pScience; }; // introduce member name "m_pScience"
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template<typename C, C> struct ChT; 

    template<typename C> static char (&f(ChT<int Fallback::*, &C::m_pScience>*))[1]; 
    template<typename C> static char (&f(...))[2]; 

    static bool const value = sizeof(f<Derived>(0)) == 2;
}; 

struct A { float m_pScience; };
struct B { int X; };

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << Hasm_pScience<A>::value << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << Hasm_pScience<B>::value << std::endl; // 0

    return 0;
}
```

The general principle to google for is SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error).

Comment: This let's you check for it, but not to conditionally do anything with it, because it will be a compiler error if you do void func() {if(Hasm_pScience<A>::value) {a.pScience = 1;}} if the Hasm evaluated to false.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you need a certain member in a template, you should force the users of the template to implement it, even if it serves no purpose for them. Common examples are stl `set` and `map` where you need to define an `operator <`.

There are many (proper) ways you can do what you want, but they all involve you requiring the user of the template to have a certain member variable or function.

You could also have two templates, one for the ones having `m_pScience` and one for those who don't, but I don't recommend this. This way, you'd have to make sure always that the code between the two templates are consistent.