# force a template argument to have specific operator

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have a template class (A). How can I force template argument to have an specific function?

```
template <class T>
class A 
{

} ;
```

T should have specific function.

Thanks

Comment: C++ is duck-typed.  So just assume it has that function, and if it doesn't the compiler will tell them the `A` is missing function `blahblah` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If your template code uses the function, compilation will already fail if `T` doesn't have it.

But if your goal is to provide clearer error messages to the users of `A`, you can use static asserts based on [checks on `T` having that member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence). Note however that you have to [watch out for inherited functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions).