# Checking a member exists, possibly in a base class, C++11 version

Tags: c++, c++11, final, template-meta-programming, type-traits

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967183/134841, a solution is provided for statically checking whether a member exists, possibly in a subclass of a type:

```
template <typename Type> 
class has_resize_method
{ 
   class yes { char m;}; 
   class no { yes m[2];}; 
   struct BaseMixin 
   { 
     void resize(int){} 
   }; 
   struct Base : public Type, public BaseMixin {}; 
   template <typename T, T t>  class Helper{}; 
   template <typename U> 
   static no deduce(U*, Helper<void (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::foo>* = 0); 
   static yes deduce(...); 
public: 
   static const bool result = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(deduce((Base*)(0))); 
};
```

However, it doesn't work on C++11 `final` classes, because it inherits from the class under test, which `final` prevents.

OTOH, this one:

```
template <typename C>
struct has_reserve_method {
private:
    struct No {};
    struct Yes { No no[2]; };
    template <typename T, typename I, void(T::*)(I) > struct sfinae {};
    template <typename T> static No  check( ... );
    template <typename T> static Yes check( sfinae<T,int,   &T::reserve> * );
    template <typename T> static Yes check( sfinae<T,size_t,&T::reserve> * );
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof( check<C>(0) ) == sizeof( Yes ) ;
};
```

fails to find the `reserve(int/size_t)` method in baseclasses.

Is there an implementation of this metafunction that both finds `reserved()` in baseclasses of `T` and still works if `T` is `final`?

Comment: On C++11 you can just use "sfinae for expressions" instead of doing this roundabout way needed in C++03.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Request for solution! I'd love to see the difference it makes for this kind of example.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Actually, things got much easier in C++11 thanks to the `decltype` and late return bindings machinery.

Now, it's just simpler to use methods to test this:

```
// Culled by SFINAE if reserve does not exist or is not accessible
template <typename T>
constexpr auto has_reserve_method(T& t) -> decltype(t.reserve(0), bool()) {
  return true;
}

// Used as fallback when SFINAE culls the template method
constexpr bool has_reserve_method(...) { return false; }
```

You can then use this in a class for example:

```
template <typename T, bool b>
struct Reserver {
  static void apply(T& t, size_t n) { t.reserve(n); }
};

template <typename T>
struct Reserver <T, false> {
  static void apply(T& t, size_t n) {}
};
```

And you use it so:

```
template <typename T>
bool reserve(T& t, size_t n) {
  Reserver<T, has_reserve_method(t)>::apply(t, n);
  return has_reserve_method(t);
}
```

Or you can choose a `enable_if` method:

```
template <typename T>
auto reserve(T& t, size_t n) -> typename std::enable_if<has_reserve_method(t), bool>::type {
  t.reserve(n);
  return true;
}

template <typename T>
auto reserve(T& t, size_t n) -> typename std::enable_if<not has_reserve_method(t), bool>::type {
  return false;
}
```

Note that this switching things is actually not so easy. In general, it's much easier when just SFINAE exist -- and you just want to `enable_if` one method and not provide any fallback:

```
template <typename T>
auto reserve(T& t, size_t n) -> decltype(t.reserve(n), void()) {
  t.reserve(n);
}
```

If substitution fails, this method is removed from the list of possible overloads.

*Note: thanks to the semantics of `,` (the comma operator) you can chain multiple expressions in `decltype` and only the last actually decides the type. Handy to check multiple operations.*

Comment: Doesn't `T` need to be a literal type in order to be a parameter to a `constexpr` function? Ok, on templates, the `constexpr` is dropped at instantiation time when it can't be `constexpr`, but you're using it in a template argument list, where it has to be.

Comment: @Marc: No, you got nearly no restrictions on what can be a parameter.

Comment: Ok, this gave me the right direction. After successive simplifications, I got it to work requiring minimal C++11 support (just `decltype`) by keeping the structure of the 2nd C++98 version, but replacing the `Yes` versions with a single `template <typename T> static decltype(static_cast<const T*>(0)->isNull(),Yes()) check(int);` one.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz: to avoid creating a null pointer, you can use `std::declval<T>()` which will return a `T` (and you can use it for with `T const&` if you wish).

Comment: Passing a class type that is not trivial enough to `(...)` isn't a good idea (e.g. it's conditionally supported). I still prefer the traditional way that use unevaluated expressions.

Comment: @Luc I think you can see it a different way: He does just function invocation substitution. Such a thing takes a function call expression and transforms it into another expression which doesn't have to be a function call anymore. In the end he has the expression `false`.

Comment: Note to future editors: I used *culls* (and not "calls") from [to cull](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cull).

Comment: I'm getting errors for both the `struct` and the `std::enable_if` versions. In the former, gcc 4.8.2 says `error: 't' is not a constant expression` (and nothing more) at line: `Reserver<T, has_reserve_method(t)>::apply(t, n);`. For the latter, it says `use of parameter 't' outside function body` in both the `std::enable_if`s. Any clue?

Comment: That is strange, I tried coliru (to get clang) but could not get it to work (execution timed out). Normally with late declared return types, you can use the arguments names starting from `->`.

Answer (score 10):

A version that also relies on `decltype` but not on passing arbitrary types to `(...)` [ which is in fact a non-issue anyway, see Johannes' comment ]:

```
template<typename> struct Void { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename Sfinae = void>
struct has_reserve: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_reserve<
    T
    , typename Void<
        decltype( std::declval<T&>().reserve(0) )
    >::type
>: std::true_type {};
```

I'd like to point out according to this trait a type such as `std::vector<int>&` does support `reserve`: here expressions are inspected, not types. The question that this trait answers is "Given an lvalue `lval` for such a type `T`, is the expressions `lval.reserve(0);` well formed". Not identical to the question "Does this type or any of its base types has a `reserve` member declared".

On the other hand, arguably that's a feature! Remember that the new C++11 trait are of the style `is_default_constructible`, *not* `has_default_constructor`. The distinction is subtle but has merits. (Finding a better fitting name in the style of `is_*ible` left as an exercise.)

In any case you can still use a trait such as `std::is_class` to possibly achieve what you want.