# Checking a member exists, possibly in a base class, VS2005/08 version

Tags: c++, visual-c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits, sealed

In [Checking a member exists, possibly in a base class, C++11 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530928/checking-a-member-exists-possibly-in-a-base-class-c11-version), we developed a C++11 version of the classical member-checking type-trait from [SFINAE to check for inherited member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions) that also works with C++11 `final` classes, but uses C++11 features (namely, `decltype`), too:

```
template<typename T>
class has_resize_method {
    struct Yes { char unused[1]; };
    struct No { char unused[2]; };
    static_assert(sizeof(Yes) != sizeof(No));

    template<class C>
    static decltype(std::declval<C>().resize(10), Yes()) test(int);
    template<class C>
    static No test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(Yes));
};
```

MSVC has had `final` as a non-standard extension named [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w2w91tf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) since VS2005, but `decltype` has only been added in VS2010. That leaves VS2005 and 2008 where a class that is marked as `sealed` still breaks the classical type-trait and the C++11 version cannot be used.

So, is there a way to formulate `has_resize_method` such that it works on VC2005/08 `sealed` classes, too?

Obviously, just as using C++11-only features to work around a C++11-only problem (`final`) is fine, so would be using VS-only extensions to work around the VS2005/08-only problem of `sealed` classes, but if there's a solution that works for all three sets of compilers {C++11,{VS2005,VS2008},all others}, that would be cool, but probably too much to ask for :)

Comment: Can you expand your question with a minimal code example, so that problem is clearer to larger audience.

Comment: `template<class C> static decltype(std::declval<C>().resize(10), Yes()) test(int);` does not compile under MSVC2010 (Unexpected end of file). It seems to be a compiler bug as the code is well-formed.

Comment: @dark_charlie: does it work with `static_cast<C*>(0)->resize(10)` instead of `std::declval`?

Comment: Considering sealed classes, the __is_sealed() built in type trait might help in some SFINAE checks (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177194(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: @dark_charlie: I'm looking for a way to make the above type trait work on compilers that support `sealed` and not `decltype`. How does detecting a classes is `sealed` help if I don't have an alternative implementation?

Comment: It does not :) I just thought it could be tangentially interesting/related. I'll check `static_cast<C*>(0)->resize(10)` when I get to a VS2010 compiler.

Comment: You want to check the name of the method only or also the specific form of the overload?

Comment: @Shawnone: in the C++98 implementation, I checked for `void resize(int)` and `void resize(size_t)`; the C++11 version above accepts more (anything that can be called with an `int`, that's why there's a `10` instead of `0`, to stay clear of implicit conversions to `nullptr`), but just a fixed signature (like `void resize(size_t)`) would be already acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution that works in all major compilers. Sadly, there is a preprocessor check for MSVC because it complains about the solution for other compilers. The main difference is that MSVC does not accept function pointers inside sizeof() and conversely, GCC does not seem to accept `(&C::resize == 0)` in the check. Clang happily accepts both.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base  {
public:
    void resize(int, int, int) { }
};

class Derived : public Base {

};

class Unrelated  { };

template<typename T>
class has_resize_method {
    struct Yes { char unused[1]; };
    struct No { char unused[2]; };

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    template <class C>
    static Yes test(char (*)[(&C::resize == 0) + 1]);
#else
    template <class C>
    static Yes test(char (*)[sizeof(&C::resize) + 1]);
#endif
    template<class C>
    static No test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(Yes));
};

int main()  {
    std::cout << (has_resize_method<Base>::value ? "Base has method resize" : "Base has NO method resize") << std::endl;
    std::cout << (has_resize_method<Derived>::value ? "Derived has method resize" : "Derived has NO method resize") << std::endl;
    std::cout << (has_resize_method<Unrelated>::value ? "Unrelated has method resize" : "Unrelated has NO method resize") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Base has method resize
Derived has method resize
Unrelated has NO method resize
```

Tested on GCC 4.5.3, GCC 4.3.4, Clang 3.0, Visual C++ 2008 and Visual C++ 2010. I don't have access to Visual C++ 2005 but I think it will work there, too. It also compiles on [Comeau Online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) but I cannot guarantee it produces a correct output there.

Works with both final and __sealed classes.

Note though that it checks not only for member functions but for member pointers in general. You might want to add additional checks such as `boost::is_member_function_pointer` if this behavior is unwanted. Similarly, you might want to add checks for number of arguments/argument types/result types - again, boost will be very helpful here, esp. [boost type decomposition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/decomposition.html).

Answer (score 2):

MSVC has a special statement **__if_exists** since vs2005. [MSDN Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7wy9xh3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You can use it to check the member function name directly. And then check the signature. Following is a simple foo detection example:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
int8_t FooCheck( void(T::*)(U) )
{
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
int16_t FooCheck( void(T::*)(double))
{
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
int32_t FooCheck(void(T::*)(int))
{
    return 0;
}


template <typename T>
class Detector
{
public:

    __if_exists(T::foo)
    {    
       enum
       {
           value = sizeof(FooCheck(&T::foo))
       };
    }
    __if_not_exists(T::foo)
    {
       enum
       {
           value = 0
       };
   }

};


std::cout << Detector<Class>::value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please reformulate as a type trait so that `has_resize_method<T>::value` is a compile-time constant, as in the question. But `__if_exists` looks promising, indeed.