# What am I doing wrong with enable_if and has_member?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I think I've been staring at this for too long or something, but I can't find my error here:

```
struct
{
    bool empty() const
    {
       return true;
    }
} hasEmpty;

template<typename T>
struct has_empty
{
private:
    template<typename U, U>
    class check {};

    template<typename C>
    static char f(check<void (C::*)() const, &C::empty> *);

    template<typename C>
    static long f(...);

public:
    static const bool value = (sizeof(f<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char));
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_empty<T>::value>::type foo(const T& t)
{

}

void x()
{
    foo(hasEmpty);
}
```

Visual Studio 2012 reports:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::enable_if<has_empty<T>::value>::type foo(const T &)'
1>          With the following template arguments:
1>          '<unnamed-type-hasEmpty>'
```

(Note, I *really* like the new C++11 version of this test as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530928/checking-a-member-exists-possibly-in-a-base-class-c11-version), but VS2012 doesn't support constexpr, yet.)

Comment: Why oh why with the unnamed struct?

Comment: Oh son of a... It's the bool.

Sorry guys, apparently a silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hasEmpty::empty` method returns `bool`:

```
struct 
{
    bool empty() const
    {
       return true;
    }
} hasEmpty;
```

But your trait uses a member function pointer that returns `void`, that substitution will always fail. You should change this:

```
template<typename C>
ctatic char f(check<void (C::*)() const, &C::empty> *);
```

For this:

```
template<typename C>
static char f(check<bool (C::*)() const, &C::empty> *);
```

That compiles for me.

Comment: Unnamed struct is not a problem!

Comment: Sigh. Like I said. I must be tired. Thanks.