# Using SFINAE to calculate the size of different elements

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

#### Introduction

I'm just begining to reading and studying about SFINAE. In order to improve my understanding I've started trying things by myself.

So I've been wondering about a useful but yet simple way to use the SFINAE powerful trick and I ended thinking about a set of functions that calculates how many bytes occupies a given type; as long as we're dealing with simple types the solution is trivial:

```
template <typename T> size_t SizeOf(const T &t)
{
    return sizeof(T);
};
```

This naive approximation would get the size of anything: 1 for `char`, possibly 4 for `int`, hopefully 4 for `char[4]` and whatever for `class PrettyAwesome` or `struct AmazingStuff` including padding bytes. But, what about the dynamic memory managed by this types?

So I would check if the given type is a pointer type then, the total size would be the size of pointer plus the size of pointed memory (if any).

```
template <typename T> size_t SizeOf(const T &*t)
{
    size_t Result = sizeof(t);

    if (t)
    {
        Result += sizeof(T);
    }

    return Result;
};
```

Yes, at this point it seems that SFINAE isn't needed at all but, let's think about containers. The `SizeOf` a container must be the sum of `sizeof(container_type)` plus the sum of the size of each of its elements, this is where SFINAE enters:

```
template <typename T> size_t SizeOf(const T &t)
{
    size_t Result = sizeof(t);

    for (T::const_iterator i = t.begin(); i != t.end(); ++i)
    {
        Result += SizeOf(*i);
    }

    return Result;
};
```

In the above code, detect if tye `T` type has a `const_iterator` is needed, and it the container is a map an specialization for pairs is needed too.

#### Questions

Finally, the questions begins here: **What have I tried and in what problems I'm stuck?**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Iterable class detector
template <typename T> class is_iterable
{
    template <typename U> static char has_iterator(typename U::const_iterator *);
    template <typename U> static long has_iterator(...);

    public:
    enum
    {
        value = (sizeof(has_iterator<T>(0)) == sizeof(char))
    };
};

// Pair class detector
template <typename T> class is_pair
{
    template <typename U> static char has_first(typename U::first_type *);
    template <typename U> static long has_first(...);
    template <typename U> static char has_second(typename U::second_type *);
    template <typename U> static long has_second(...);

    public:
    enum
    {
        value = (sizeof(has_first<T>(0)) == sizeof(char)) && (sizeof(has_second<T>(0)) == sizeof(char))
    };
};

// Pointer specialization.
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, size_t>::type SizeOf(const T &aValue)
{
    size_t Result = sizeof(aValue);

    if (aValue)
    {
        Result += sizeof(T);
    }

    return Result;
}

// Iterable class specialization.
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<is_iterable<T>::value, size_t>::type SizeOf(const T &aValue)
{
    size_t Result = sizeof(aValue);

    for (T::const_iterator I = aValue.begin(); I != aValue.end(); ++I)
    {
        Result += SizeOf(*I);
    }

    return Result;
}

// Pair specialization.
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<is_pair<T>::value, size_t>::type SizeOf(const T &aValue)
{
    return SizeOf(aValue.first) + SizeOf(aValue.second);
}

// Array specialization.
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value, size_t>::type SizeOf(const T &aValue)
{
    size_t Result = sizeof(aValue);

    for (T *I = std::begin(aValue); I != std::end(aValue); ++I)
    {
        SizeOf(*I);
    }

    return Result;
}

// Other types.
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, size_t>::type SizeOf(const T &aValue)
{
    return sizeof(aValue);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int Int;
    int *IntPtr = &Int;
    int twoints[2] = {0, 0};
    int *twointpointers[2] = {IntPtr};
    std::string SO("StackOverflow");
    std::wstring WSO(L"StackOverflow");
    std::map<std::string, char> m;
    std::vector<float> vf;

    m[SO] = 'a';

    std::cout << "1: " << SizeOf(Int) << '\n';
    // std::cout << "2: " << SizeOf(IntPtr) << '\n';
    // std::cout << "3: " << SizeOf(twoints) << '\n';
    // std::cout << "4: " << SizeOf(twointpointers) << '\n';
    std::cout << "5: " << SizeOf(SO) << '\n';
    std::cout << "6: " << SizeOf(WSO) << '\n';
    std::cout << "7: " << SizeOf(m) << '\n';
    std::cout << "8: " << SizeOf(vf) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces this output:

```
1: 4
5: 45
6: 58
7: 66
8: 20
```

1. If I uncomment the lines with the 2, 3 and 4 output the compiler shows the "*ambiguous call*" error. I really had thought that the output 2 will use the `is_pointer` speciallization and the output 3 and 4 will use the `is_array` one. Well, I was wrong but I don't know **why**.
2. I'm not fine with the way I get the total size of a container, i think that iterating all the items and calling the `SizeOf` for each item is a good choice but not for all the containers, in `std::basic_string` doing `sizeof(container) + sizeof(container::value_type) * container.size()` would be faster but I cannot realize **how to specializate for `basic_string`**.
3. Talking about the *detection classes* (like the ones that detect iterable and pair), in some [blogs articles](http://debugfailure.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/understanding-sfinae/) and web examples about SFINAE I've seen that is a common practice to create a `true_type` and `false_type` `typedef`s, usually defined as `char` and `char[2]`; but I've found that some authors uses `char` and `long` as `true_type` and `false_type`. **Anyone knows wich one is the best practice or the *most standard* one**?.

Note that I'm not looking for answers like *why you don't try "this library" or "this tool"*, my goal is practicing and understanding the SFINAE, any clue and advice is wellcome.

Comment: 1). because array name — its a pointer to its first cell. They are recognized as pointers. Hence you have ambiguous call. I'd recommend you to use another version of overloaded `SizeOf` for pointers. Calculating array size is better with `sizeof( _array ) / sizeof( _array[0] )`.
2). In this case should be used template-parameters for template. Like: `template <typename T, template <typename> class Container> std::enable_if<...>::type SizeOf( const T& _value )` where inside you can declare a variable `Container<T>`. Which will be specialized for std::basic_string.

Comment: 3). No difference, since long and char have different sizes (I hope in all compilers).

Comment: @Pie_Jesu: No, an array name is not a pointer to its first element. It can _convert_ to one. This is critically important in overload resolution, which is decided based on the best _conversion_ sequence.

Comment: @MSalters are right, recently [R. Martinho Fernandes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) advice me to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810668) to understand the `array[]` vs `pointer` relationship..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your "specializations" for pointers etc. are in fact not specializations. They're overloads.
2. The compiler first performs overload resolution, and only then checks for specializations. There's formally no such thing as an "ambiguous specialization". Your cases 2,3 and 4 fail already in overload resolution, precisely because you have no specializations.
3. Overload resolution is decided on argument types only. Your overloads only differ in return type. Certainly some overloads may be disabled, but you would need to disable *all* overloads but one. Currently, a POD array enables both your POD and array overloads.
4. For a container, the better solution is probably to use `Container.size()`.
5. `char[2]` is preferred because `sizeof(long)` can be 1, according to the standard.

One question not asked, which I'll answer anyway, is "how should I write the array overload then"? The trick there is a reference to an array:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N> 
constexpr size_t SizeOf(const T (&aValue)[N])
{
  // return N * sizeof(T); If you want to do the work yourself
  return sizeof(aValue); // But why bother?
}
```

Comment: And there's a way to check if the `T::size()` (or any other method) exists? I think that I've seen somewhere that is possible to do it.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530928/checking-a-member-exists-possibly-in-a-base-class-c11-version

Comment: Thanks! I bet that's just what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

1.You should read about POD concept in C++11. Array of POD-type elements or pointer to POD-type element are POD-types  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType

For example following code will compile well http://liveworkspace.org/code/81627f5acb546c1fb73a69c45f7cf8ec

2.Something like this can help you

```
template<typename T>
struct is_string
{
   enum
   {
      value = false
   };
};

template<typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
struct is_string<std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>>
{
   enum
   {
      value = true
   };
};
```

Functions

```
// Iterable class specialization.
template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<is_iterable<T>::value && !is_string<T>::value, size_t>::type SizeOf(const T &aValue)
{
    size_t Result = sizeof(aValue);

    for (typename T::const_iterator I = aValue.begin(); I != aValue.end(); ++I)
    {
        Result += SizeOf(*I);
    }

    return Result;
}

template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<is_string<T>::value, size_t>::type SizeOf(const T& aValue)
{
   return sizeof(aValue) + sizeof(typename T::value_type) * aValue.length();
}
```

3.No information in standard, that `sizeof(long)` should never be equal to `sizeof(char)`, but `sizeof(char)` cannot be equal to `sizeof(char[2])`, so, second variant is preferable i think.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question #3, I think that in C++11, it's much cleaner (and more clear) to use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) instead of `sizeof` to obtain an [integral constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) such as `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

For example, your `is_iterable`:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::true_type, std::false_type

// Iterable class detector
template <typename T> class is_iterable {
  template <typename U> static std::true_type test(typename U::const_iterator *);
  template <typename U> static std::false_type test(...);

public:
   // Using decltype in separate typedef because of gcc 4.6 bug:
   // http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6709
   typedef decltype(test<T>(0)) result_type;
   static const bool value = result_type::value;
};
```