# What does the 'void()' in 'auto f(params) -> decltype(..., void())' do?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, decltype, trailing-return-type

I found code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531274/1594090) that looked something like this:

```
auto f(T& t, size_t n) -> decltype(t.reserve(n), void()) { .. }
```

In all the documentation I read I was told that `decltype` is signed as:

> `decltype( entity )`

or

> `decltype( expression )`

And there is no second argument anywhere. At least that's what's pointed to on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype). Is this a second argument to `decltype`? And if so, what does it do?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Since it is an expression that comma is simply the comma operator (meaning the type is the type of the rhs side: `void`), not another argument.

That code is using SFINAE - it's enabled if `t.reserve(n)` exists but it wants to keep the return type as `void`.

Comment: I never would have guessed. Thanks.

Comment: @templateboy: The comma operator always springs up in the most unexpected places ;)

Comment: OMG we seriously need language constructs to not have to write such hacky tricks! O__O;;;

Comment: @Klaim: This is a lot nicer than SFINAE usually ended up being before C++11.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, but this is more obscure!

Comment: @Waleed Khan Will C++14 concepts end with SFINAE?

Comment: Just curious if the use of "void()" itself is by at all possible just because we're in an unevaluated context

Comment: @abigagli Yes, `void` is an incomplete type so you can't call its "constructor" anywhere outside an unevaluated context like `decltype()` or `sizeof()`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Not true. You can use `void()` anywhere a void prvalue is allowed (granted, there's not very many...)