# Type trait to check if istream operator>> exists for given type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, declval

I found this type trait which can be used to check if a certain type `T` supports `operator<<`:

```cpp
template<class Class>
struct has_ostream_operator_impl {
    template<class V>
    static auto test(V*) -> decltype(std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<V>());
    template<typename>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

    using type = typename std::is_same<std::ostream&, decltype(test<Class>(0))>::type;
};

template<class Class>
struct has_ostream_operator : has_ostream_operator_impl<Class>::type {};
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/szymek156/9b1b90fe474277be4641e9ef4666f472

This works fine. Now I'm trying to do the same thing for `operator>>` using c++11, but I don't get it to work:

```cpp
template<class Class>
struct has_istream_operator_impl {
  template<class V>
  static auto test(V*) -> decltype(std::declval<V>() >> std::declval<std::istream>());
  template<typename>
  static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

  using type = typename std::is_same<std::istream&, decltype(test<Class>(0))>::type;
};

/**
 * @brief Type trait to check if operator>>(std::istream, Type) is defined for a given type.
 */
template<class Class>
struct has_istream_operator : has_istream_operator_impl<Class>::type {};
```

Here is a simplified test for my use case:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// <include snippet 2>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_istream_operator<T>::value, T>::type
fromString(const std::string& str) {
  T value;
  std::istringstream stream(str);
  stream >> value;
  return value;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << fromString<long>("123") + 1 << std::endl; // expecting 124
  return 0;
}
```

Error is:

```
has_istream_operator.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
has_istream_operator.cpp:57:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘fromString<long int>(const char [4])’
   std::cout << fromString<long>("123") + 1 << std::endl; // expecting 124
                                      ^
has_istream_operator.cpp:49:1: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> typename std::enable_if<has_istream_operator<Class>::value, T>::type fromString(const string&)’
 fromString(const std::string& str) {
 ^~~~~~~~~~
has_istream_operator.cpp:49:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
has_istream_operator.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> typename std::enable_if<has_istream_operator<Class>::value, T>::type fromString(const string&) [with T = long int]’:
has_istream_operator.cpp:57:38:   required from here
has_istream_operator.cpp:49:1: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, long int>’
```

From which I understand that the SFINAE condition is false and therefore no definition of `fromString` exists.

What I have tried is to play around with the line

```cpp
static auto test(V*) -> decltype(std::declval<V>() >> std::declval<std::istream>());
```

inside my definition of `struct has_istream_operator_impl`.

This is the variation which makes most sense to me, because when I use the operator>>, I usually do it this way: `stream >> value` for example and from my (limited) understanding, the `test(V*)` should test this generically for `V`:

```cpp
static auto test(V*) -> decltype(std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<V>());
```

But it does also not work (same error).

How do get I this to work?

Comment: Turn `decltype(std::declval<V>() >> std::declval<std::istream>())` into `std::declval<std::istream>()) >>decltype(std::declval<V>()`.    Although it may make sense to you for the `istream` to be on the right hand side of a `>>` expression,  `operator>>()` for `istream`s are not specified that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, you should change

```cpp
static auto test(V*) -> decltype(std::declval<V>() >> std::declval<std::istream>());
```

to

```cpp
static auto test(V*) -> decltype(std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<V&>());
```

There were two errors in the code, due to the following.

- The `>>` operator takes the stream as first argument, not as second argument, whereas you are passing the two arguments the other way around.
- `declval<V>()` is generating an rvalue (well, not really a value because we are in an unevaluated context), to which you can't assign a value via `>>` (just like you can't `cin >> 123;`), so you have to change it to `declval<V&>()`.(¹)

##### Update

In reality, prompted by @brahmin's comment, I have to point out another bug in the original code. Follow this reasoning:

- The first overload (including my correction) `has_istream_operator_impl<T>::test` is correctly chosen if `>>` makes sense between an `std::istream` (any value category) and a `T&` (lvalue);
- however, `has_istream_operator_impl<T>::type` will incorrectly test if ***the return type*** of the call to `test<T>(0)` is `std::istream&`.
- Doing so is a mistake, because there's many overloads of `operator>>` and they don't all return `std::istream&`:

  ```cpp
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    decltype(std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<std::string&>()),
    std::istream&&>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    decltype(std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<int&>()),        
    std::istream&>);
  ```

What you want to do, is to have `has_istream_operator_impl<T>::type` be `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` ***only*** depending on whether `std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<V&>()` is valid , not on depending on its return type!

One typical approach to do so is to use [`decltype` with two arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044514/what-is-decltype-with-two-arguments) (or to [`static_cast<void>` the result of one-argument `decltype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837332/sfinae-static-castvoid-or-void))

```cpp
    static auto test(V*)
      -> decltype(std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<V&>(), void());

    using type = typename std::is_same<void, decltype(test<Class>(0))>::type;
```

So the correct code would be the following

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct has_istream_operator_impl {
  template<typename V>
  static auto test(void*) -> decltype(std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<V&>(), void());
  template<typename>
  static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

  static constexpr bool value = std::is_same_v<decltype(test<T>(nullptr)), void>;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_istream_operator = has_istream_operator_impl<T>::value;
```

where I've made some cosmetic changes:

- made `has_istream_operator` a value rather than a type, so the usage is less verbose:

  ```cpp
  static_assert(has_istream_operator<int>);
  static_assert(!has_istream_operator<int*>);
  static_assert(has_istream_operator<std::string>);
  ```
- used `void*` rather than `V*` for the "positve" `test` function parameter, as that has nothing to do with with `V`,
- changed `0` to `nullptr` because we are passing it to a function taking a pointer,
- changed `class` to `typename` as using both is confusing or at least distracting, imho.

---

¹ To understand more in depth why that's the case, look at the possible implementation of `std::declval` as shown at [the documentation page on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval): as you can see, it returns the type `typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type` (which, incidentally, can be written as `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` [since C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference)), i.e. `std::declval<T>()` returns `T&&`, which is (by reference collapsing)

- an lvalue reference if you provide an lvalue reference `T` to `std::declval` (e.g. `std::declval<int&>()`),
- an rvalue reference otherwise (e.g. `std::declval<int>()`).

In your usecase you are passing `long` as the `T` to `std::declval`, so we are in the second case, i.e. `std::declval<long>()` returns `long&&`. From the page on [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) you can see that an example of xvalue (which is, just like a prvalue, an rvalue) is the following (my **emphasis**):

> **a function call** or an overloaded operator **expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object**, such as std::move(x);

And that's exactly what `std::declval<long>()` is: it has a rvalue reference to object as its return type, hence it returns an rvalue.

If you call, instead, `std::declval<T&>()` and pass `long` as `T`, the call will be `std::declval<long&>()`, in which case the return type will be `long&`, hence the call will return an lvalue. See the following quote, from the same page, of an example of lvalue

> **a function call** or an overloaded operator expression, **whose return type is lvalue reference**;

To give an example of what `std::declval` is doing, these both pass

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<int>()), int&&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<int&>()), int&>);
```

and this fails to compile

```cpp
int x;
std::cin >> static_cast<int&&>(x); // XXX
```

where the `// XXX` line is what `std::declval<std::istream>() >> std::declval<V>()` is "emulating".

Comment: It does not seem to work for classes (using C++11). Example: fails using std::string

Comment: @brahmin, please, provide a link to [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) with the failing example.

Comment: Sure, something like : https://godbolt.org/z/zncEehqPn

Comment: @brahmin, I was wrong with my previous (now deleted) comment. I've addressed your question in my answer, now. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. To be noted: the modification should also apply on std::ostream of the OP (which does not work either). Simply changing std::istream to std::ostream and >> to << on your (very correct) answer seems to do the job for both has_ostream_operator and has_istream_operator