# Is expression inside decltype executed, or just being checked for validation?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

By using [Expression SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae), you can detect if some [operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839357/detect-operator-support-with-decltype-sfinae) or [operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003366/what-does-the-void-in-auto-fparams-decltype-void-do) is supported or not.

for example,

```
template <class T>
auto f(T& t, size_t n) -> decltype(t.reserve(n), void())
 { t.reserve(n); }
```

My question is that `t.reserve(n)` inside `decltype` get executed or not?

If yes, does that mean `t.reserve(n)` got executed twice, one inside `decltype` and the other one inside the function body?

If not, is it just checked for validation during compilation time? But why it is not executed, I thought all the expressions in the comma separated expression list will get executed.

Comment: It's not executed no. (You could have verified by putting a breakpoint in it and calling f)

Comment: `decltype` is an *unevaluated-operand*. The expression(s) inside are not executed because only the types they yield are needed. If the expression(s) are not well-formed, then you have a substitution failure (in this case).

Comment: I don't quite believe that `void()` is legal.

Comment: @ex-bart Believe it.

Comment: @ex-bart, I think `void` itself is not an expression, so you should put `void()` since it is part of the comma separated expression. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Barry Woah, indeed it is.

Comment: @Allanqunzi I didn't think that `void()` was legal, since that would create a value of type `void`, and I thought that can't be right since `void` is an incomplete type. I *did* know that there are expressions of type `void` (i.e. calls to functions returning `void`), and that those expressions can be used in certain places, such as the comma operator.  But `void()` is just another special case specifically for void which I didn't previously know about. (See C++11 §3.9.1[basic.fundamental]/9 and §5.2.3[expr.type.conv]/2)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, from [dcl.type.simple]:

> The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5).

which means, from [expr]:

> In some contexts, unevaluated operands appear (5.2.8, 5.3.3, 5.3.7, 7.1.6.2). An unevaluated operand is not
>   evaluated. An unevaluated operand is considered a *full-expression*.

So in this particular context, the purpose of `decltype(t.reserve(n), void())` is to verify that `t.reserve(n)` is a valid expression. If it is, then the function is a viable overload whose return type is void, and `reserve()` will be called exactly once (in the function body). If it is not, then we have a substitution failure and the function is not a viable overload candidate.

Comment: I see, thank you. I just feel C++ always surprise me and wonder how would I know this stuff in advance.

Comment: @Allanqunzi Nobody knows stuff in advance. Everybody didn't know it at some point.