# SFINAE decltype comma operator trick

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

After reading Matthieu's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531274/955273), I decided to try this myself.

My attempt fails to compile because SFINAE doesn't kick in and cull the `has_foo` function which attempts to access `T::foo`.

```
error: ‘struct Bar’ has no member named ‘foo’
```

Am I missing something, or is what I'm attempting to do not possible in this way?

(I'm using gcc-4.7.2)

Full examplar below:

```
#include <iostream>

// culled by SFINAE if foo does not exist
template<typename T>
constexpr auto has_foo(T& t) -> decltype((void)t.foo, bool())
{
    return true;
}
// catch-all fallback for items with no foo
constexpr bool has_foo(...)
{
    return false;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------

template<typename T, bool>
struct GetFoo
{
    static int value(T& t)
    {
        return t.foo;
    }
};
template<typename T>
struct GetFoo<T, false>
{
    static int value(T&)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
//-----------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
int get_foo(T& t)
{
    return GetFoo<T, has_foo(t)>::value(t);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------

struct Bar
{
    int val;
};

int main()
{
    Bar b { 5 };
    std::cout << get_foo(b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pass in `has_foo<T>(0)` instead of `has_foo(t)` and change `has_foo` to take in a pointer to t, i.e. `auto test(T* t) -> decltype(t->foo, bool())`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The primary issue here AFAICS is that you are using the *run-time* reference as a `constexpr` function parameter. Replacing this works just fine.

```
#include <iostream>

// culled by SFINAE if foo does not exist
template<typename T>
constexpr auto has_foo(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().foo, bool())
{
    return true;
}
// catch-all fallback for items with no foo
template<typename T> constexpr bool has_foo(...)
{
    return false;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------

template<typename T, bool>
struct GetFoo
{
    static int value(T& t)
    {
        return t.foo;
    }
};
template<typename T>
struct GetFoo<T, false>
{
    static int value(T&)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
//-----------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
int get_foo(T& t)
{
    return GetFoo<T, has_foo<T>(0)>::value(t);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------

struct Bar
{
    int val;
};
struct Foo {
    int foo;
};

int main()
{
    Bar b { 5 };
    Foo f { 5 };
    std::cout << get_foo(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_foo(f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Follow up if I may. You are using an `int` parameter (and passing value of this type) to distinguish between catch all, and catch this. Let's say I have a requirement that I shall take `foo` or `bar` member value (in that order). Is this method suitable for this task, or other route should be taken?

Comment: @RedXIII: Yes, this method is suitable. In the catch-all case, just use `.bar`. If there's a `.foo`, the first method is used. If there's no `.foo` but there is a `.bar`, the catch-all is chosen and it compiles. If there's neither, the catch-all is chosen and it doesn't compile.

Comment: @RedXIII: Yes, you can extend it to more than one by using say, `int` and `long`, (order `int` -> `long` -> `...`)but you can also customize this to an arbitrary preference by using base classes.

Comment: Yes, the concept is evident from the code, but introductory text that explains the change you're making would be useful.