# SFINAE check failure

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

the following SFINAE test fail to check wether something is a duck (it is a duck if there is a "void quack()" member function). I don't understand why. Any idea ?

```
struct Duck
{
    void quack() {}
};

struct Pig
{
    void groink() {}
};

template<class T>
auto test_duck(const T& t, int)
    -> decltype(t.quack(), bool())
{
    return true;
}

template<class T>
auto test_duck(const T& t, long)
{
    return false;
}

template<class T>
bool is_duck(const T& t)
{
    return test_duck(t, 0);
}    

int main()
{
    Duck duck;
    Pig pig;

    cout << is_duck(duck) << endl;  
    cout << is_duck(pig) << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's the output you're getting?

Comment: `void quack() {}` is not const-qualified, and so not viable for a call thourgh a const reference

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki : ...... Im' so dumb.... It does the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFINAE decltype comma operator trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265536/sfinae-decltype-comma-operator-trick)

Comment: Of course `quack()` can't be `const` since it causes the duck to deflate a little.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing a `const Duck&` but `Duck` only has a non-const `quack()` method.

Edit: Looks like comments already figured it out in time. If @PiotrSkotnicki wants to post an answer (instead of answering in the comments) I'll delete this.