# Clang complains about undefined constexpr function in unevaluated context

Tags: c++, constexpr, clang++

I’m using a simple SFINAE trick to check whether a member function exists, like so:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename C>
struct has_size {
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T*) ->
        decltype(std::declval<T const>().size(), std::true_type{});

    template <typename>
    static constexpr auto check(...) -> std::false_type;

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(check<C>(nullptr))::value;
};

// Usage:
static_assert(has_size<std::vector<int>>::value, "std::vector<int> has size()");
```

(I’m aware that [there’s a simpler method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531274/1968) now, but wasn’t back when I wrote this piece of code.)

This code works on GCC. Clang however issues a warning<sup>1</sup> (all versions up to Apple LLVM 7.3, whichever that is upstream):

```
decltype.cpp:15:27: error: inline function 'has_size<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >::check<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >' is not defined [-Werror,-Wundefined-inline]
    static constexpr auto check(T*) ->
                      ^
decltype.cpp:22:44: note: used here
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(check<C>(nullptr))::value;
```

In other word, clang expects the functions to be defined, not just declared, even though they are never called (only in the unevaluated context of `decltype`).

Is this a bug in clang? Or is it right to complain? If so, is GCC also correct in accepting this code?

Furthermore, while writing this question I realised that the clang compilation error can be avoided altogether by removing the `constexpr` qualifier in front of the member function template. What does the presence of `constexpr` change here?

---

<sup>1</sup> Which is a problem as I’m compiling with `-Werror`. There are some warnings that are based on heuristics and therefore have unavoidable false positives, but this isn’t the case here as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't intending ever to call a function, there's no point marking it `constexpr`.

`constexpr` on a function isn't visible to the type system (well, except that pre-C++14 it had the side effect of making a non-static member function `const`); rather, it's a promise that for at least one combination of template type arguments and function arguments (and object state, for a non-static member function) the body of the function can be *evaluated* as a constant expression (or an algorithm equivalent to a constant expression). Conversely, the lack of `constexpr` on a function is an instruction to the compiler not to even attempt to evaluate the function body as a constant expression.

Clang isn't *correct*, exactly, but it isn't *incorrect*, either, as you've specifically asked it to reject valid programs (with `-Werror`). You should take the warning-error as a strong hint that `constexpr` functions without a definition are a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree. The fact that I made these functions `constexpr` doesn’t make any sense. I was just puzzled that it seemingly changes the way unevaluated context sees them.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bug in clang? Or is it right to complain? If so, is GCC also correct
>   in accepting this code?
>
> Furthermore, while writing this question I realised that the clang compilation
>   error can be avoided altogether by removing the `constexpr` qualifier in front
>   of the member function template. What does the presence of `constexpr` change
>   here?

Compiler warnings are outside the C++ standard. Warnings are issued for valid programs that contain indications of human error. In your particular case, you chose to qualify with a `constexpr` a function that you did not define. Programs using that class will be valid only if you never call that function. If that's really the case then `constexpr` is not needed. But what if you intended to call that function (though forgot to provide an implementation for it), but due to some mistake (complex overload resolution, or just a stupid typo) a different function was called?

Thus Clang has its point in issuing the warning. However, it is arguable whether that situation deserves a warning; personally I wouldn't file a bug against GCC.

Comment: The warning is generated at the call site (which *isn’t* a call site), that’s what makes me suspect that this is a bug: clang seems to think that I will call the function.

Comment: A warning isn't necessarily generated at the call site. Example: https://godbolt.org/g/GbWxNp

Comment: I know, but in this case it is.