# Compile-time solution to detect that an Eigen object does not have an eval() member?

Tags: c++, c++11, evaluation, eigen

Most Eigen classes have an `eval()` method that force their evaluation. Some classes don't, for example matrix decompositions. Is there a way to distinguish between these classes at compile-time?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions).

Comment: I was aware of that answer, but I was looking for an eigen-specific solution.

Comment: What do you mean by an Eigen-specific solution?

Comment: classes that have `eval()` probably inherit from some class I'm not aware of. But your solution is cool I must admit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own trait which uses SFINAE to determine this:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    auto has_eval_impl(void*)
        -> decltype(std::declval<T>().eval(), std::true_type());

    template<typename T>
    auto has_eval_impl(...) -> std::false_type;
}

template<typename T>
struct has_eval : decltype(detail::has_eval_impl<T>(nullptr)) { };
```

Comment: why do you need to pass arguments to `has_eval_impl`?

Comment: @yannick Overload resolution only works between functions with parameters. If I leave both parameters empty the compiler will tell me that I can't overload based on the return type.