# Check if a type has a member function (inhrited member functions also) with Boost TTI

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits

[Boost TTI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/doc/html/index.html) has very convenient macros for checking if a type has a member function. [See here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_member_function.html).

But [BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_member_function.html) returns false for inherited member functions. Is there a convenient Boost solution for this?

I am aware of an existing thread for a custom [SFINAE solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions). But I would prefer a Boost solution, since that way I am more sure it works on more compilers and I want avoid maintaining code for each such specific behavior. Also I am already using something similar libraries from Boost.

Comment: What is the use case for this? It's likely that there is a more elegant way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Are you okay with a non-boost, SFINAE solution?

Comment: I guess there is already a thread for a custom [SFINAE solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions). But I would prefer a Boost solution, since that way I am more sure it works on more compilers and I want avoid maintaining code for each such specific behavior

Comment: Probably th closes answer is [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15685535/1686769), but it does not correctly handles arguments properly in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Edward Diener, the creator of the library, informs us in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/awd4kqJezfQ) :

> TTI cannot identify inherited member functions even if they are public.

So since you still want to use TTI, let's make a work around. I'll be using an example similar to the related manual pages in BOOST, only inheritance will be added to the 'problem' :

```
struct AClass { };

struct Top {
    int function1();
    AClass function2(double, short *);
};

struct Top2 : Top {
    long function2(Top &, int, bool, short, float);
    Top * function3(long, int, AClass &);
};

int main()
{
    cout << has_member_function_function1<Top, int>::value << endl;; // 1. true
    cout << has_member_function_function1<Top2, int>::value << endl; // 2. false
    return 0;
}
```

Case (2) is an error since a function named `function1` returning an `int` is defined in the base class of `Top2`, class `Top`

### 1. Mechanism to check across a hierarchy of classes

First step will be to build a mechanism that would apply **TTI checks** to an arbitrary number of classes :

```
template <
    template <class, class, class, class> class check,
    typename Ret, typename... Bases
>
struct has_m_f;


template < 
    template <class, class, class, class> class check, 
    typename Ret, typename Base
>
struct has_m_f <check, Ret, Base>
{
    static const bool value = check<Base, Ret, 
        boost::mpl::vector<>, boost::function_types::null_tag>::value;
};


template < 
    template <class, class, class, class> class check, 
    typename Ret, typename Base, typename... Bases
>
struct has_m_f <check, Ret, Base, Bases...>
{
    static const bool value = check<Base, Ret, 
        boost::mpl::vector<>, boost::function_types::null_tag>::value 
        || has_m_f<check, Ret, Bases...>::value;
};
```

`has_m_f` is a struct that forwards an arbitrary length of classes to `has_member_function_...` structs, which will be doing the check. No algorithm is added, just a mechanism to elevate the predicate using existential quantification :

> if any of the classes ascending the hierarchy has such a member function then return true

With this tool, in your case, you could write

```
has_m_f < has_member_function_function1, int, Top2, Top >::value;
```

The template arguments are :

1. The struct that checks for the member function (eg `has_member_function_function2`)
2. The return type of the function
3. Arbitrary number of classes in the hierarchy

### 2. Auto producing the base classes

The above workaround suffers from the fact that you have to manually supply the base classes. **When practicing generic programming, being specific is a drawback**.

A way to have this kind of introspection is through [**std::tr2::bases**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/api/a00907.html). If you have an implementation that supports it (it's going to be standard in a "while") you can at last have your introspection using TTI :

```
has_m_f < has_member_function_function1, int, Top2,
            std::tr2::bases<Top2>::type >::value;
```

HTH