# Detecting at compile-time whether a class has a member variabe or function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl

I'm trying to detect at compile time whether a class `Foo` or `Bar` has *either* the variable `value` or member variable `initValue()`.

```
struct Foo
{
    static const int value;
    static int initValue();
};

struct Bar
{
};
```

I've found several boost and boost MPL classes and utils such as `BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF` and `valid_member_metafunction` that appear to do just this but am unsure which to use. I know it's possible to roll out my own detector but I'd rather not.

Comment: [Check is a member exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005476/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-member-variable-in-class) and [check if a method exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249199/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-member-exists-in-a-struct); put them together with `std::enable_if`

Comment: @Dave Thanks but I'd rather not roll out my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. `has_static_member_data` and `has_static_member_function` from the [Boost TTI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/doc/html/index.html) library.

```
#include <boost/tti/has_static_member_data.hpp>
BOOST_TTI_HAS_STATIC_MEMBER_DATA( value ) // Generates class template has_static_member_data_value
...
has_static_member_data_value<Foo, int>::value;  // returns true
has_static_member_data_value<Bar, int>::value;  // returns false
```