# check whether a field exists in a struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect whether there is a specific member variable in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005476/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-member-variable-in-class)

I have a templated function that takes a struct as a parameter. If the struct contains the field "id" the function may continue, something like:

```
template<typename PointT>
void doSomething(PointT point) {
  if (containsField(point, "id")) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

I'm aware of specialization, unfortunatly PointT can be any type that has field id
I believe I saw something similar in boost a while ao but can't find it anymore

any ideas??

Comment: If `PointT` can be any type, that function should be a function template, right?

Comment: You probably need [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

Comment: for C++11 there is a simpler solution than the one in the linked question that I would like to provide, but I cannot do that if the question is closed

Comment: I don't have enough rights to reopen it, but maybe you can answer it in the linked question and let me know

Comment: @MoatazElmasry: done that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005476/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-member-variable-in-class/14523787#14523787