# Execute or skip code based on template parameter contents

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to create a container for an arbitrary type T. However, I want to add some functionality if T has a member that is header type (which I also define). If T does not have that header member, then the added functionality can just be skipped.

The added functionality might, for example, be to add a timestamp based on when an operation is performed. Here's pseudo code for what I want:

```
struct my_header {
  timestamp_t time;
  // ... etc ...
}

template <class T>
class my_container {
  public:
    void some_operation(T val) {
        // condition evaluated at compile time
        if T has a member of type my_header {
            val.header.time = get_current_time();
            // ... etc ...
        }

        // other operations, agnostic to T
    }
};
```

of course as I have it, some_operation also has to figure out the name of the instance of my_header in class T. This requirement could be eliminated by imposing one of the following requirements for the added functionality to be used (in order from most to least preferable):

- The instance of `my_header` in class T must have the name `header`
- The instance of `my_header` is the first member variable in class T
- class T derives from my_header instead of including it as a member variable

Using C++11 is fine (expected in fact).

Comment: You can check based on having something with the name `header` that is a `my_header`, but not from not knowing the name without the class telling you.

Comment: @Ken You want to check type of T?

Comment: Exactly how would this work? Wouldn't the code fail to compile regardless of how you check for the existence of the variable (because of `val.header.time`). I think the solution would involve specializations.

Comment: @remyabel Tag dispatch can be your friend here.

Comment: I found this from another answer I had and changed it a bit. Try it out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb4dfd66f03561bc. @Xeo, you might find it familiar :p

Comment: Tangential FYI: if only that function is using templates, you can templatize only that function rather than templatizing then entire class.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but I think it can work. Stolen code from [How to detect whether there is a specific member variable in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005476/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-specific-member-variable-in-class)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct my_header {
  int time;
};

// begin stolen code
template<typename T, typename V = bool>
struct has_header : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_header<T, 
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().header), void>::value, 
        bool
        >::type
    > : std::true_type { };
// end stolen code

struct foo
{
    my_header header;
};

template<typename, typename = void>
class my_container;

template<typename T>
class my_container<T, typename std::enable_if<has_header<T>::value>::type>
{
public:
    T val;
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << val.header.time << "\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
class my_container<T, typename std::enable_if<!has_header<T>::value>::type>
{
public:
    T val;
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "other.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_container<foo> c;
    my_container<int> c2;
    c.foo(); // garbage
    c2.foo(); // other.
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to refine the answer by using `enable_if` on `some_operation` instead of the container type

Answer (score 1):

remyable's solution is not bad (+1), but it can be simplified:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct my_header {
  int time = 0;
};

template<typename T>
using has_header = std::is_same< decltype( T::header ), my_header >;

struct foo
{
    my_header header;
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
class my_container
{
public:
    T val;
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "other.\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class my_container<T, typename std::enable_if<has_header<T>::value>::type>
{
public:
    T val;
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "time: " << val.header.time << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_container<foo> c;
    my_container<int> c2;
    c.foo(); // time: 0
    c2.foo(); // other.
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/835ce1c11918e3d7)

Of course this solution still uses the requirement that the member variable is called `header` is C++ does not have introspection which can iterate a type's members.