# type detector `hasNestedType` not compiling?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am trying to make a meta function which tells me if a type `T` has a
member type `typename T::X`.

My luck so far was inspired by [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16000226/293195):

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {using X = double;};
struct B {};

template <typename T, typename = int>
struct hasX : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct hasX<T, decltype(T::X{}, 0)> : std::true_type {};


int main() 
{
   static_assert(hasX<A>::value,"Should have has X");
   static_assert(!hasX<B>::value,"Should NOT have X");
}
```

However it does not compile, and I am wondering what the problem is?
Why is the comma operator in `decltype(...)` not working like I want *[returning `0` if `T::X` succeeds (sfinae) -> making it a `int` -> `true`]*

[Result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cc35986f893bf9f)

Comment: Pro tip: If you don't want to rely on `X` being default-constructible, you can replace `typename = int` with `typename = void`, and `decltype(typename T::X{}, 0)` with `std::void_t<typename T::X>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat perfect, thanks :-)!

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten a `typename`

```
template <typename T>
struct hasX<T, decltype(typename T::X{}, 0)> : std::true_type {};
// .....................^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ah how stupid, thx alot! compiler error msg... should get even better