# How to check if a c++ class has a given static member variable, wihtout any prior struct definition?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

I would like to check if a type `T` has a static member variable `name`: `T::name`.
I saw a lot of solutions (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16000226/5317819, https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/5317819), but they all require to define first a template struct somewhere before the check, while knowing a priori what is the name of the member.

What I would like is something very 'lightweight' so that inside any function I can do:

```cpp
if constexpr(HAS_MEMBER_VARIABLE(T,name)) {
    // T::name exists
}
```

Existing solutions all require to define a template struct such as

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = int>
struct Has_name : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct Has_name <T, decltype((void) T::name, 0)> : std::true_type { };

#define HAS_MEMBER_VARIABLE(TYPE,NAME) Has_name<TYPE>::type
```

How to achieve this without knowing a priori what is the `NAME`?

Moreover, if in my code I have to check if a type has a member `feature_1`, `feature_2`, ..., `feature_N`, I have to declare first `N` struct, and I have to know every `feature_i` in advance.

To simplify the issue, we can make the hypothesis that the static member variable is of type `bool` if it exists. I am also open for using macros. But the solution needs to be usable at compile time.

Comment: With C++20 concepts you can  just `if constexpr(requires { T::name; })`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62292282/1145526

Comment: @康桓瑋 Can that test if the member is static?